# LISP cons in python

Tags: python, lisp, cons

Is there an equivalent of `cons` in Python? (any version above 2.5)

If so, is it built in? Or do I need `easy_install` do get a module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, it's more typical to use the array-based `list` class than Lisp-style linked lists.  But it's not too hard to convert between them:

```
def cons(seq):
    result = None
    for item in reversed(seq):
        result = (item, result)
    return result

def iter_cons(seq):
    while seq is not None:
        car, cdr = seq
        yield car
        seq = cdr

>>> cons([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
(1, (2, (3, (4, (5, (6, None))))))
>>> iter_cons(_)
<generator object uncons at 0x00000000024D7090>
>>> list(_)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 10):

WARNING AHEAD: The material below may not be practical!

Actually, `cons` needs not to be primitive in Lisp, you can build it with λ.
See [Use of lambda for cons/car/cdr definition in SICP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769348/use-of-lambda-for-cons-car-cdr-definition-in-sicp) for details. In Python, it is translated to:

```
def cons(x, y):
    return lambda pair: pair(x, y)

def car(pair):
    return pair(lambda p, q: p)

def cdr(pair):
    return pair(lambda p, q: q)
```

Now, `car(cons("a", "b"))` should give you `'a'`.

How is that? Prefix Scheme :)

Obviously, you can start building list using `cdr` recursion. You can define `nil` to be the empty pair in Python.

```
def nil(): return ()
```

Note that you must bind variable using `=` in Python. Am I right? Since it may mutate the variable, I'd rather define constant function.

Of course, this is not Pythonic but Lispy, not so practical yet elegant.

Exercise: Implement the List Library http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html of Scheme in Python. Just kidding :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that Python's lists are implemented as vectors, not as linked lists. You could do `lst.insert(0, val)`, but that operation is O(n).

If you want a data structure that behaves more like a linked list, try using a [Deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque).

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, you can use the splat operator `*` to do this concisely by writing `[x, *xs]`. For example:

```py
>>> x = 1
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [x, *xs]
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```

If you prefer to define it as a function, that is easy too:

```py
def cons(x, xs):
  return [x, *xs]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can quite trivially define a class that behaves much like `cons`:

```
class Cons(object):
    def __init__(self, car, cdr):
        self.car = car
        self.cdr = cdr
```

However this will be a very 'heavyweight' way to build basic data structures, which Python is not optimised for, so I would expect the results to be much more CPU/memory intensive than doing something similar in Lisp.

Answer (score 1):

No. `cons` is an implementation detail of Lisp-like languages; it doesn't exist in any meaningful sense in Python.

Comment: so there's no way to "condense" lists like from `[1, 2, [3, 4, 5, [4, 1]]]` to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 1]`?

Comment: There is, but `cons` isn't it. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python